# Choosing Elements from numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Code=

`a = np.array(['Phone', 'Laptop', 'Phone', 'Pi_Board', 'Pi_Board', 'Laptop', 'Phone'])`

In numpy array `a`, there are some elements are repeated regularly.

the `np.random.choice()` have the option to add probability values for every elements/items, but how to mention the probability value by every unique element

How to choose random elements from `a` by providing the probability values like, lets say,

`'Phone' - 0.7 probability`

`'Laptop' - 0.2 probability`

`'Pi_Board' - 0.1 probability`

Thanks

Comment: you should just make another array ith the elements and use `sample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [`numpy.random.choice()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) you can use `numpy.random.choice(list(set(a)), 1, [0.7, 0.2, 0.1])`.

If you wanted to derive the probabilities from `a` you can use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import numpy, collections

a = numpy.array(['Phone', 'Laptop', 'Phone', 'Pi_Board', 'Pi_Board', 'Laptop', 'Phone'])

counter = collections.Counter(a)

print(numpy.random.choice(list(set(a)), 1, [counter[c]/len(a) for c in set(a)]))
```